# Getting the Wrong Data type for a property using Entity Framework.Extensions Future query

Tags: c#, mysql, entity-framework, entity-framework-extended

I am using Entity Framework 6.1.3 with MySQL 5.6.  I have the following query:

```
var qAccounts = _repository.GetAll<vw_account>(m => m.CustomerId == customer.Id).Future();
```

Later on I iterate through qAccounts using a foreach loop. But as soon as I try to do this I get the following error:

> "An error occurred executing the future query."

The inner exception is more revealing:

> "The type of the key field 'IsDefault' is expected to be 'System.Boolean', but the value provided is actually of type 'System.UInt64'."

In the database, IsDefault is a boolean.  It is a Boolean in the model for this view, (vw_account) too.  If I remove .Future() from the query to make it execute immediately, I do not have this problem.

Anyone know why?

Comment: Did you check the SQL queries?

Comment: I added some code so that I could see the SQL in the Output window.  Perhaps interestingly, I do not see the query when I use Future().  When I do not use it, it looks pretty standard:

Comment: SELECT
`Extent1`.`Id`, 
`Extent1`.`CustomerId`, 
`Extent1`.`IsDefault`, 
`Extent1`.`IsActive`, 
`Extent1`.`Name`
FROM `vw_account` AS `Extent1`
 WHERE `Extent1`.`CustomerId` = @p__linq__0